# Thread-safe data structure for storing event multiplexer data (epoll, etc.)

Tags: c++, multithreading, epoll

I'm trying to create an efficient, multi-threaded event multiplexer (using epoll on linux, and iocp on windows)

For each event source I add to epoll, I need to store some additional information.

At first, I've used a dynamically growing array for this (because of cache-coherency), but as it turned out, it is not a good solution, as I need to keep the protecting mutex locked for too long.

```
// this function is OK, performance wise
void Multiplexer::add(int fd) {
    mutex.lock();
    <add fd int my array>
    mutex.unlock();
    <add fd into epoll, setting epoll_data.u32 to fd's index in the array>
}

void Multiplexer::poll() {
    events = <call_epoll>
    mutex.lock();  // here, I need to keep mutex locked for a long time, as array can grow from a different thread which calls add
    for (events) { // or, the other solution could be that I lock/unlock mutex each time in the for loop, which is bad for performance
         <handle_event_using_array>
    }
    mutex.unlock();
}
```

My second idea is to use list, but this way I may loose the good property of cache-coherency (it may be not that important, so I probably will go this way).

Is there any better data structure for this problem? Or any better idea how to solve this problem?